# Unable to use replace in order to rename cells

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, xlsx

Currently I have some JavaScript within a .hta application which opens a .xlsx workbook, saves each sheet as a CSV file and then removes blank columns/rows.

I am trying to introduce a new step which renames any cells which contain a single question mark `"?"` in the spreadsheet to a blank `""`.

The idea is this renaming step happens prior to deleting blank rows/columns.

When I execute the below code the question marks are still present in the csv files? Why is the renaming not working as intended?

```
          // Open the workbook.
          var wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(aFile.Path);
          log('Successfully opened the file.');

          // Save each worksheet as a CSV file.
          var sheetNum = 0;
          for(var sheetIndex = 1, sheetCount = wb.Sheets.Count; sheetIndex <= sheetCount; sheetIndex++) {

        var ws = wb.Sheets.Item(sheetIndex);
        var wsName = ws.Name;
        var usedRng = ws.UsedRange;

        //Replace "?" with ""

    var num_col = ws.UsedRange.columnCount
var num_row = ws.UsedRange.rowCount

for (i = 0; i < num_row; i++) { 
for (j = 0; j < num_col; i++) { 
    ws.UsedRange.getCell(i,j).values = ws.UsedRange.getCell(i,j).values.replace("?","");
}
}

        //Remove all blank rows

        for(var i = usedRng.Rows.Count; i > 0; i--){
            if( xlApp.CountA(usedRng.Rows(i)) == 0 ) usedRng.Rows(i).Delete();
        }

        //Remove all blank columns

    for(var i = usedRng.Columns.Count; i > 0; i--){
        if( xlApp.CountA(usedRng.Columns(i)) == 0 ) usedRng.Columns(i).Delete();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about JS, but I do know in Excel if you are deleting rows within a loop, you need to loop backwards.

Comment: The deleting columns/rows part works fine, the issue is regarding the find and replace

Comment: I understand, but when you delete row 3 for example, row 4 becomes the **new row 3**, so the old row 4 is completely skipped in the next iteration of your loop when performing your `.replace("?","")` method.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I see, that should be changed then as every single row should be looked at

Comment: As I stated early, I don't know JS, but if this were VBA you would do something like `For i = 20 to 1 Step -1` so you would step backwards. Hopefully that's a starting point for you.